# How can I see "Tests and Coverage" in pipeline summary while approvals are pending?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the pipeline summary I expect to see the test pass percentage and the coverage percentage. However, because there are stages pending approvals, the pipeline is still considered "in progress" and the section is blank/empty: [image: pipeline tests pending]

I think the pipeline summary contains useful information for the approval to take place, so I would expect that data to be available even before all stages are complete.

Is there an alternative way to consider the pipeline completed, see the test and coverage numbers, and then still have the ability to manually trigger/complete some of the skipped stages?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one wondering this. If it isn't already supported, it really ought to be.